# Using eq() and find() to add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a few divs within a containing div, eg:

```
<div id="container">

 <div class="itmeholder">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="itmeholder">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="itmeholder">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="itmeholder">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

I want to add a class to the 2nd 'item' div, so I created:

```
$('#container:eq(1)').find('.item').addClass('newclass');
```

This isnt working. I have also tried using `nth-child()` as well, also to no avail.

Can anyone suggest to me a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you want:

```
$('#container').find('.item').eq(1).addClass('newClass')
```

Comment: Note that this will get unexpected results if you have multiple `.item` elements inside the first `.itemholder`.

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing `#` for id selector, also need to modify the selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/qpc3d/)**,

```
$('#container .itmeholder:eq(1)').find('.item').addClass('newclass');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#container').find('.item').eq(1).addClass('newclass');​
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you target the container separately:

```
$('#container')
```

Then fetch its children, limiting it to only the 2nd child:

```
    .children(':eq(1)')
```

The perform the rest of your search and action:

```
    .find('.item')
    .addClass('newclass');
```

Complete code:

```
$('#container')
    .children(':eq(1)')
    .find('.item')
    .addClass('newclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container .itmeholder:eq(1)').find('.item').addClass('newclass');
```

First find the inner element childs and use  eq to find the required item and add class to it